# Observable.map setTimeout function with return type in angular 5

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I would like to wait a little inside an Observable.map function and then returning a value

My Code is:

```
public loginRequest(userCredentials: any): Observable<TSUser | undefined> {

    return this.http.post<TSUser>(this.serviceURL + '/login', userCredentials).map((response: any) => {

        window.setTimeout(() => {
            this.initWithCookie();
            return this.principal;
        }, 300);
        //error TS2322: Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<TSUser | undefined>'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'TSUser | undefined'.

    });

};
```

How can i return the correct Observable type with an setTimeout function. With my code i get the error
    `error TS2322: Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<TSUser | undefined>'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'TSUser | undefined'.`

If i do it with:

```
public loginRequest(userCredentials: any): Observable<TSUser | undefined> {

    return this.http.post<TSUser>(this.serviceURL + '/login', userCredentials).map((response: any) => {

        return Observable.timer(300).map(() => {
                this.initWithCookie();
                return this.principal;
            }).take(1);
    });

};
```

I get the error 
    `error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Observable<TSUser | undefined>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<TSUser | undefined>'.`

**Solution**
According to the answer from martin my working code is

```
public loginRequest(...): Observable<TSUser | undefined> {

        return this.http.post<TSUser>(...).delay(300).concatMap(response => Observable.of(this.initWithCookie()));

};
```

(I would like to wait 300ms **before** i execute the code in my function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to not use `setTimeout` and let RxJS make the delay for you with the `delay()` operator:

```
return this.http.post<TSUser>(...)
  .concatMap(response => Observable.of(response).delay(300));
```

You could use `setTimeout` but then you'd have to use `Observable.create(observer => {})` and emit the result inside `setTimeout` to `observer.next(...)` which is unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0):

With RxJS v6, import and usage syntax of operators has been changed.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

return of({delay_time: 3000}).pipe(
  concatMap(response => of('Delayed by: ' + response.delay_time + ' ms').pipe(delay(response.delay_time)))
);
```